# Can I claim that the range of $\sin(x)$ in the given equation must be necessarily $[-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I have this equation
$$a \sin (x)+b \cos (x)+c=0$$
I want to obtain $\sin (x)$ in terms of other parameters. Substituting $\;\cos (x)=\sqrt{1-\sin ^2(x)}$, and then, solving the quadratic equation, I get
$$\sin (x)=\frac{-a c\pm \sqrt{a^2 b^2+b^4-b^2 c^2}}{a^2+b^2}$$
My question is since I have substituted $\;\cos (x)=\sqrt{1-\sin ^2(x)}$ in the original equation, then, can I claim that the range of the result must be necessarily in $[-1,1]$?

Since when I evaluate the result for random parameters, I see that sometimes it gives imaginary values, and, in those cases, the real part is greater than $1$ and smaller than $-1$.

Comment: For real $x$, we have $\sin(x) \in [-1,1]$. What is the meaning of $[-1,1]$ when dealing with complex numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**

Your equation can be written as

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x+\alpha)=-c$$

with $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

So, to have real solutions, you need the condition
$$|\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}|\le 1$$

Comment: Thanks. I have a new question in a new post. I wonder if you could have a look and tell me your opinion. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799588/can-i-claim-that-fx-must-be-necessarily-positive-in-the-given-inequality