# Can I claim that $f(x)$ must be necessarily positive in this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

I have this inequality

$$-x^2-\left(x^4 \cos (3 x)+9 x^2\right)\;\leq \sqrt{f (x)}\;\leq\; \left(x^4 \cos (3 x)+9 x^2\right)-x^2$$
where $\;f (x)=x^4 \cos (\pi  x)+x-\cos (x),\;$ and $x>0$. As can be seen, the functions on the LHS and RHS of the inequality always give real results, but, the function $f(x)$ for some values of $x$ can be negative and hence, for those values, $\sqrt{f (x)}$ will have imaginary parts as well.

My question is since the LHS and RHS are always real, can I claim that $f(x)$ must be necessarily positive?

In other words, is this inequality valid only for $f(x)>0$?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put complex numbers into an inequality. So the statement wouldn't make sense if f(x) were negative.

Comment: since the complex numbers are not ordered, the symbol $\leq$ would not make sense for complex numbers, and so the whole inequality only makes sense for values $x$ sth $f(x)\geq 0$ but $f$ is oscillating between negative and positive numbers, as you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4*cos%28%CF%80*x%29%2Bx%E2%88%92cos%28x%29)

Comment: @PeterMelech Thanks. And this is my question that since $f(x)$ can get negative values, and since inequality does not make sense for the complex plane, then, can I claim that $f(x)$ must be necessarily positive?

Comment: it'd be fun if you had $| \sqrt{f(x)} |$

Comment: The inequality is only valid over a range of values of $x$, and over that range $f(x)$ is necessarily positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the OP's official question, not only *can* you claim that $f(x)$ must be non-negative (note the inclusion of $0$), you *must* claim it. The only way not to do so would be to redefine the inequality symbol in some weird way.

In other words, for the OP's function, let

$$I_f=\left\{x: -x^2-\left(x^4 \cos (3 x)+9 x^2\right)\;\leq \sqrt{|f (x)|}\;\leq\; \left(x^4 \cos (3 x)+9 x^2\right)-x^2\right\}$$

and

$$N_f=\left\{x:f(x)\ge0\right\}$$

Then the solution to the OP's inequality is $I_f\cap N_f$. Neither $I_f$ nor $N_f$ appears at all easy to solve for explicitly; it would be remarkable if their intersection were any easier.